# Trying to find a sci-fi story about navigating e-space (or maybe it was h-space)

Tags: story-identification

About 18 or so years ago, someone gave me a science fiction collection book and I no longer have it, but I remember a specific story about a guy traveling through space with a pilot that was a white-furred chimpanzee that could talk. The pilot of the craft was exceptionally suited for navigating the "e-space" (or "h-space") lines that allowed travel between different parallel universes. In one instance they woke up in this giant forest of cylindrical shapes - and came to realize they were miniature and looking up at the room from the fibers in the carpet. 
Sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: You've provided some interesting details to begin with, but could I suggest you take a look at [this checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help improve your question with more details.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Part of the [Uplift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Brin#The_Uplift_stories) saga by David Brin. At least some of this happens in the third volume of the second trilogy, [Heaven's Reach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaven%27s_Reach), I'm not sure if the carpet incident was in the second or third book.

The *uplifted* Chimp, Harry Harms, was not originally white-furred (and he had no tail), but extremely weird quantum effects in *E-level* hyperspace do strange things to travelers.

Comment: Yes! That's it - wow, thank you so much!!!